# Limiting records number of days and count

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-limit

Let's say I have a table in MySQL DB with following columns

`employee, status, work, start_date`

Consider that `start_date` column is date and time.

If I do

```
SELECT employee, status, work, start_date from table_name WHERE DATE(date) >= CURDATE()-10
```

this will give me records from Current `date` - 10 days. In this case I might get 1 record to 100 records based on the data.

I need only 10 records based on date/time (e.g. if there are 10 employees that started to work today then I should get only today's records and not 10 days record)

How can I do that?

Comment: So... you are looking for `LIMIT 10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want the ten most recent entries? You can add an ORDER BY to set the order in which the results come back, and a LIMIT to reduce the total number of results.

```
SELECT employee, status, work, start_date from table_name 
WHERE DATE(date) >= CURDATE()-10
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `order by` on start_date and `limit`

```
SELECT employee, status, work, start_date 
from table_name 
order by start_date desc
limit 10
```